# Turning path in file to softlink automatically in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox, symlink

I am using virtualbox `(ubuntu 16.04, host : win10)` for a project and I have a file `utils` containing a single-line path `../../system_utils`, which I need to use `ln -s` command to turn it into a real softlink.

However, on a azure virtual machine of the same ubuntu configuration, I found that file `utils` automatically becomes a softlink. It now becomes as follows :

`utils -> ../../system_utils`

I suspect there is some different setting between a virtual box and virtual machine causing this. I therefore wonder how I could achieve the same way on virtualbox so the path could be softlinked automatically ? Any idea would be helpful !

Comment: What do you mean "you found it automatically becomes"? How did you notice that it's a link? This _must_ be a script, because a symlink _is not a regular file_. If you want it to "link automatically", you have to create a script that reads all files, decides if they're link files, if yes removes them an replaces them with symlinks to their destination. I wouldn't advise trying to turn regular files into symlinks, as it's not intended to be used this way. You might break things.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:

1. Add the symlink to the Virtualbox, this is permanent, after restart it's still there.
2. I don't think in Azure this can happen. Never heard a linux system is able to create links from existing files alone. Could be there is some script doing this, but this is not part of the ubuntu system.
3. Symlink could be already saved in git and when you pull the project in Azure the symlink is created. Git saves symlinks.